# use \footcite and \cite with different style in the main body text

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` package and want to use `\cite` or `\parencite` in `authoryear` format but `\footcit`e in `verbose`. If I change to `citestyle=verbose`, everything will be in verbose format. How can I get the solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 2):

With the standard styles `\footfullcite` should give you a full, verbose-style citation in the footnotes.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \parencite{sigfridsson}
dolor\footfullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Full citation in footnote.]

Depending on what exactly you have planned, it may be more useful to additionally redefine `\footcite` to typeset those full citations - or maybe to typeset the full entry on first citation and a shorter version on subsequent citations of the same work. The "best" solution strongly depends on why you need to use two different citation styles in your document.